# How to save cookies coming from a .net backend server in Angular

Tags: angular, cookies, angular9, setcookie, .net-5

The backend server is .net 5 and is able to send and receive cookies. I can see the cookies in postman so I know that the backend is sending and receiving cookies. I then tried to get angular to receive these cookies however nothing happens. Where do I load the cookies for angular that come from a backend server?

Im guessing it would be in the service section of angular

Below is the angular code for logging in. It receives a token from the .net backend. Where would I put the code to receive and send the cookie.

```
login(model: any) {
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model)
  .pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
        const user = response;
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
        }
    })
  );
```

}

Comment: Don't use local storage or cookies, if your user has these settings disabled you're app won't work. That happens more than you think btw, not everyone is tech savy and understand local storage and cookies and how their browser manages them.Use `ngrx` to manage the state of the token and user.

Comment: Im using the cookies for 2FA. Tokens will still be used for authentication but i need cookies saved as well.

Comment: Why didn't you use document.cookie to save the cookie?

Comment: How do you use document.cookie?